# Full Flex Display Object to Image

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a requirement for generating a UIComponent displayed into an Image. Am using the PNGEncoder as well as JPEGEncoder to generate the image.

```
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(uiComp.measuredWidth,uiComp.measuredHeight);
bd.draw(uiComp, new Matrix()); 
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd); 
bytes = jpgenc.encode(bd);
```

The code is working perfectly in normaly scenarios. But the problem comes in low resolution screens, if the canvas is having scroll bar, only the displayed contents, i mean omitting the contents belows the scrolled location is coming. Is there any way that I can convert the complete canvas completely into an image, even if it having scroll bar! Please help!

Cheers, PK

Answer (score 1):

I think ImageSnapshot can take a screenshot even if the component is cut off or even if its visible property is set to false.

```
import mx.core.IUIComponent;
import mx.graphics.ImageSnapshot;

private function takeSnapshot(source:IBitmapDrawable):void {
    var imageSnap:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(source);
    var imageByteArray:ByteArray = imageSnap.data as ByteArray;
    swfLoader.load(imageByteArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks KreeK. But do you know how to integrate this byte array with JPEGEncoder or PNGEncoder. There is encodeByteArray method for JPEGEncoder, but that is giving me error #2030:End of file was encounterd error. :-(

Comment: This guy has an example of going to JPG or PNG, I think you should be able to post that data and save as a file on the backend. http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/12/07/using-the-imagesnapshot-class-to-capture-images-as-jpegs-or-pngs-in-flex-3/

Answer (score 0):

Using Imagesnap with PNGEncoder i was able to get the Screenshot with compression

```
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import mx.graphics.ImageSnapshot;
import mx.graphics.codec.PNGEncoder;
```

...
...
...
...

```
ImageSnapshot.defaultEncoder = PNGEncoder;
var imageSnap:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as IBitmapDrawable);
var stream:FileStream = openStream("screenshot.png");
stream.writeBytes(imageSnap.data);
stream.close();
```

...
...
...
...

```
private static function openStream(fileName:String):FileStream
    {
        var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(fileName);
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        return stream;
    }
```